# Mongodb: add a date field/column to documents which do not have a date field

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection called posts, initially they only had "text" and "author" field. Later I added a "date" field for later posts.

How I can add a date field for initial posts, for those who does not have date/created-at field.

I guess I need to use following two commands, but cant figure out how to make the connection (i.e. loop)?

```
db.posts.find({"date":{"$exists":false}}
ObjectId(_id).getTimestamp()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
db.posts
  .find({"date":{"$exists":false}) // looking for records without `date` field
  .forEach(function (record) { // iterating through each record
      record.date = null; // if you want to define current date use `new Date()`
      db.posts.save(record); // saving updated record
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is a `forEach()` function that you could use. [forEach](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/)

```
db.posts.find({"date":{"$exists":false}).forEach(<function - do something>)
```